# How to use a TextBlock that allows the left-most characters to be dropped

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have the following scenario which I thought would have a simple solution, but I'm stumped...

I have constructed a WPF user control with a set of numeric Buttons and a TextBlock to record what buttons have been selected.  When the user control opens, the TextBlock is empty.  As a button is selected, the digit it represents is appended to the right-hand-side of the displayed text.

What I need is a solution where the digits keep getting appended on the right-hand-side and if that results in exceeding the fixed displayable size of the TextBlock dropping the left-most character.  In effect I am after a one-character-at-a-time marque effect.

I can not use scroll bars.  Any thoughts would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special at the TextBlock level... Just pass it the string that is formatted correctly using something like [string.SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

**UPDATE:** This code should do the trick:

```
const int maxLength = 8;

string value = "sdfdfdfsdffdsfsdf";

if (value.Length > maxLength)
   value = value.Substring(value.Length - maxLength);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done, I was just hoping that there was a "simple" XAML solution, i.e. some tag attribute I didn't know about

Comment: You could use a valueconverter, but that's about it

Comment: @Oh and it's usually nice to post the solution that you've already done so people don't duplicate your work just so you can say "Yes, that's what I've done."

Comment: Sorry, new to the forum; I will do so in the future.  Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Databindings are you friend here.

suppose you got a ViewModel. and in the ViewModel you got a property of string which is binded to the TextBlock Text propetry.

Now you only need to manipulate that string inside the ViewModel using regular c# string methods to display correctly.
HTH

Ariel

Comment: I like MVVM, but if the asker is having problems displaying a substring, that might be a little much.